# If some text is rotated x degrees then how would I work out how far the leftmost point is from the original leftmost point?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, geometry

I'm drawing some text on to an HTML5 canvas, turning the canvas in to an image which is overlayed on to a second canvas, the img is then rotated by the user and then drawn on to the second canvas. The issue I have is that when the image is drawn on to the canvas it isn't in the correct position. I've attached some images to demonstrate this:

This is the img tag which the user can drag and rotate:

[image: absolute positioned img tag]
<sub>(source: [devjoe.co.uk](http://devjoe.co.uk/before.png))</sub>

This is what happens when the image is drawn on to the canvas (ignore the red box)
[image: the result]
<sub>(source: [devjoe.co.uk](http://devjoe.co.uk/after.png))</sub>

I can't figure out why the image is being offset. If it is horizontal then it is drawn in the correct place, the more I rotate it the further away it ends up. Here is the javascript that draws the image on to the canvas:

```
function saveWatermark()
{
toggleLoading(true);
enableUndo();
var watermarkOffset = $('.watermark').offset();
var watermarkWidth = $('.watermark').width();
var watermarkHeight = $('.watermark').height();
var canvasOffset = $(_canvas).offset();
//TODO: If the text is a long string then the rotate handle is too close and it moves jerkily
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function ()
{
    $('.watermark-container').remove();
    if (!_watermarkAngle)
    {
        _context.drawImage(img, _watermarkX, _watermarkY);
    } else
    {
        _watermarkAngle = Math.round(_watermarkAngle);
        _context.save();
        var xPos = watermarkOffset.left - canvasOffset.left;
        var yPos = watermarkOffset.top - canvasOffset.top;
        var xCentre = xPos + img.width / 2;
        var yCentre = yPos + img.height / 2;

        _context.translate(xCentre, yCentre);
        _context.rotate(_watermarkAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        _context.translate(-xCentre, -yCentre);
        _context.drawImage(img, xPos + (img.width / 2), yPos + (img.height / 2));
        _context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)';
        _context.fillRect(xPos, yPos, img.width, img.height);
        _context.restore();

    }
    $btnWatermarkSave.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    toggleLoading(false);
};
img.src = $('.watermark')[0].src;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: It seems that the img.width / 2 bit should be img.width / ? - not sure what this value is - it changes depending on how much the image has been rotated.

Comment: Just out of interest, is this watermark intended to discourage people from re-using your background images for their own purposes? If so, if it is done on the client side, it can be disabled easily.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps check `line-height` of the text too - it could have a bigger 'box' than we see ?

Comment: perhaps not ... looks like an offset center as another idea to look into ( rotating on an offest center )

Comment: I too would suggest making sure the rotation is happening around the center you think it is happening around.